# ExtAudioFileWrite in iOS failing with error code -66560

Tags: ios, extaudiofile

I'm using ExtAudioFileWrite to write audio data into a file. But when it is interrupted by an alarm, although the file is saved, I get this error.
What kind of error is this?

Comment: Are you sure error code is -66560? extAudioFile function returns following return codes http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/ExtendedAudioFileServicesReference/Reference/reference.html

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To decode an error from core audio, search the header files of the framework. In this case, you can look in ExtendedAudioFile.h for -66560, which will lead you to: 
`kExtAudioFileError_CodecUnavailableInputNotConsumed`